# Nice looking exception messages in terminal for Node.js

Tags: node.js, error-handling, exception, package

Node.js displays standard exception messages in terminal, that are:

- messy
- hard to understand
- pointing to lines in compiled js files.
- making it hard to tell, **where an error in question is located in sources**.

Is there a package, that makes standard output more nicer and shows, which line made exception in sources.

I looking for plug and play solution, that will just work out the box.

Thanks.

Comment: This question might draw very opinionated answers. That being said, check out [pretty-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-error). There are other packages in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) depending on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> pointing to lines in compiled js files.

The errors are pointing to lines of the code that is actually being executed. Node doesn't know if you wrote it yourself or not.

It seems that you're using a transpiler (which you didn't mention in the question) and that is not something that I necessarily recommend, nor it is a common use case in Node development. But when you do use a transpiler for whatever reason then you need to use Source Maps to have the errors point to the original source code and not the transpilation result, just like you do on the frontend. Search for Source Maps support in Node and Babel or whatever transpiler you're using.

Unfortunately you're unlikely to find exactly what you ask for, i.e. a plug and play solution, that will just work out the box, making errors less messy and easier to understand. Errors are usually complicated things with a lot of context and Node is already doing a pretty good job of providing that context. But you can always write your own handler to print better error messages having the context available in the Error object - See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

In practice you should never rely on Node's printing the Error object directly. You should write your own meaningful and easy to understand error messages, preferably using a module like Winstonm, Bunyan, Log4js, etc. to handle and log the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

**Most popular: verror**

The error classes it supports:

- printf-style arguments for the message
- chains of causes
- properties to provide extra information about the error
- creating your ownsubclasses that support all of these

> 518,775 downloads in the last day
>
> 3,387,126 downloads in the last week
>
> 13,950,439 downloads in the last month